# EF7 beta6: Error saving multiple entities

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am creating an API using ASP.NET5 and Entity Framework 7.0.0-beta 6, and when I try to execute various updates in several requests, I get this Exception:

*'Company' cannot be tracked because another instance of this type with the same key is already being tracked. For new entities consider using an IIdentityGenerator to generate unique key values.*

This is my code:

```
public class MrBellhopContext : DbContext
{

    public DbSet<Company> Company { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Company>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Key(c => c.CompanyId);

            entity.Index(c => c.Name);

            entity.Property(c => c.CompanyId).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
        });

        modelBuilder.UseSqlServerIdentityColumns();

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

}


public class Company
{

    public int CompanyId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string Phone { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public short StatusId { get; set; }

}


public class CompanyRepository : ICompanyRepository
{

    MrBellhopContext _dbcontext;


    public async Task UpdateAsync(Company company)
    {
        _dbcontext.Update(company);
        await _dbcontext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}



[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class CompanyController : Controller
{


    [HttpPut]
    public async void UpdateAsync([FromBody] Company company)
    {
        if ((!ModelState.IsValid) || (company == null))
        {
            Context.Response.StatusCode = 400;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            await _repository.UpdateAsync(company);
        }
    }

}
```

I have tried to solve it by removing *ValueGeneratedOnAdd()*, *UseSqlServerIdentityColumns()* or changing the mapping, but if I try to update several entities in several requests, I get the Exception:

1. First req: Update CompanyId 8
2. First req: Update CompanyId 9  !! ERROR

**Does anyone know how to solve this issue?**

Comment: Have tried to add the `[Key]` attribute to the primary key property, which is in your case `ComapnyId`?

Comment: the error says that you have two Company instances with the same ID. By looking at your code doesn't look like the case but I can't be sure. Can you show the caller to UpdateAsync ?

Comment: @Bart Yes, sure. I include the code.

Comment: I think that there is something that still alive in the DBContext after execute the first operation; and when I execute the second one, fails

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Resolved: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2652

I was adding Repository as a Singleton:

```
services.AddSigleton<Data.Interfaces.Company.ICompanyRepository,Data.Repositories.Company.CompanyRepository>();
```

*This means that all requests are sharing a single instance of the repository. You should reduce this to Scoped, so that you have a single repository instance per request. Aside from avoiding the issue you are hitting, it will also ensure you don't end up with a gigantic context instance tracking all the data from your database in memory.*

To solve:

```
services.AddScoped<Data.Interfaces.Company.ICompanyRepository,Data.Repositories.Company.CompanyRepository>();
```

Comment: This fixed it for me in ASP 5 vNext with EF 7

Comment: There was already an answer by @natemcmaster that was explaining issue and providing a solution. Maybe you could have credited his answer, apart from providing your solution anyway for future readers.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this error because your instance of `_repository` already has an instance of `Company` in memory with the same key. This can happen when you are reusing an instance of DbContext across threads. Your sample above doesn't include the code about how `CompanyController._repository` gets instantiated. Make sure this is not shared between HTTP requests.

Also, put this line before you configure the key.

```
entity.Property(c => c.CompanyId).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
```

Answer (score 0):

Even I was facing the same issue.

I was registering the Repositories as singleton in Configure method of startup.cs file. Changing that to `AddScoped` fixed the issue.

Just need to use the below code to update the records

```
_dbContext.Company.Update(company);
_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```