# ASP.NET 5 EF 7 cannot update entry in database table

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am creating an API that will enable CRUD functionality to Create, Read, Update, and Delete record in database.

I am running into an issue that is not allowing me to update entry inside a table due to an instance is shared and I get below error.

`cannot be tracked because another instance of this type with the same key is already being tracked. For new entities consider using an IIdentityGenerator to generate unique key values."`

Here is my code:

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
        public JsonResult Put(int Id, [FromBody]PackageVersion updatePackage)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    if (updatePackage == null || updatePackage.Id != Id)
                    {
                        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
                        return Json(new { status = "Bad Request" });
                    }

                    var package = _respository.GetPackageById(Id);
                    if (package == null)
                    {
                        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
                        return Json(new { status = "Not Found", Message = package });
                    }

                    _respository.UpdatePackage(updatePackage);
                    if (_respository.SaveAll())
                    {
                        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Accepted;
                        return Json(updatePackage);
                    }
                }
                Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
                return Json(new { status = "Failed", ModelState = ModelState });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
                return Json(new { status = "Failed", Message = ex.Message });
            }
        }
```

In the above code you will notice I am first getting a record by using repository `_repository.GetPackageById(Id)`, which allows me to validate that a record is in database and I can continue to update by using `_repository.UpdatePackage(updatePackage)` repository. If I comment out below code in my controller, I am able to save the data in the database.

```
//var package = _respository.GetPackageById(Id);
//if (package == null)
//{
//    Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
//    return Json(new { status = "Not Found", Message = package });
//}
```

I also made sure that I was using AddScoped in startup configuration as mentioned in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31392842/ef7-beta6-error-saving-multiple-entities/31840042#31840042).

```
services.AddScoped<IAutomationRepository, AutomationRepository>();
```

I am not sure why I cant use multiple DBContext instances for same ID when it is called.

Any suggestion is really appreciated. :)

**UPDATE 1:**

```
public class AutomationRepository : IAutomationRepository
    {
        private AutomationDBContext _context;

        public AutomationRepository(AutomationDBContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public void AddPackage(PackageVersion newPackage)
        {
            _context.Add(newPackage);
        }

        public void DeletePackage(int id)
        {
            var package = _context.PackageVersions.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);
            _context.PackageVersions.Remove(package);
        }

        public IEnumerable<PackageVersion> GetAllPackages()
        {
            return _context.PackageVersions.OrderBy(p => p.PackageName).ToList();
        }

        public object GetPackageById(int id)
        {
            return _context.PackageVersions.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);
        }

        public bool SaveAll()
        {
            return _context.SaveChanges() > 0;
        }

        public void UpdatePackage(PackageVersion updatePackage)
        {
            _context.Update(updatePackage);
        }
```

Comment: Why not using scoped context instead of using multiple ?

Comment: you mean `_context.TableName`?

Comment: Maybe. Show us the repository impelmentation.

Comment: Added update 1 in my original post.

Comment: show us what is in GetPackageById() method

Comment: @janina, it's in update 1 in my original post with class name `AutomationRepository`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your repository method like below. This may help. Let us know what happens

```
public object GetPackageById(int id)
{ 
 return _context.PackageVersions.AsNoTracking().SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id ==id);
}
```

Comment: Glad it helped. But you may need to refactor your repository to avoid this kind of situation.